# Ошибки при отправке клавиатур / аудио на aiogram python

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Пишу бота для Телеграм и столкнулся с проблемой при отправке аудио, если написать такой код, тогда музыка отправляется на ура:

```
async def sent_vk_audio(call):
    await bot.send_audio(
                    call.message.chat.id,
                    audio='https://dl1.i-tsmusic.com/vk.play.php?id=371745454_456344136&vk_hash=375_133a3fe7458fafd604_8b62ea008b7113b395&hash=d4d83ea7e4650940a634238be6ab7ed5&name=badi-gr_bad-word.mp3',
                    caption='`  это тест`',
                    parse_mode='MarkdownV2'
                )
```

Итак вот тоже на отлично музыка отправляется с этими сокращенными ссылками, для скачивания .mp3 музыки:

```
async def sent_vk_audio(call):
    await bot.send_audio(
                    call.message.chat.id,
                    audio='https://qps.ru/C8iL7',  # также https://is.gd/9BSe6P
                    caption='`  это тест`',
                    parse_mode='MarkdownV2'
                )
```

Если прикрепить эти callback_data - `https://qps.ru/C8iL7` или даже эту - `https://is.gd/9BSe6P` ( прошу заметить не как url, а как callback_data к инлайновой кнопке ) и пытаться отлавливать нажатую кнопку с этой callback_data, после пытаться вызвать функцию отправки аудио, которая выше `sent_vk_audio()`, это код обработчика нажатия инлайновых кнопок:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def callback_handler(call):
    print(call.data) # вывод "https://qps.ru/C8iL7" либо "https://is.gd/9BSe6P"
    
    if 'https://dl1.i-tsmusic.com' in call.data:
        await sent_vk_audio(call)
        
    elif 'https://qps.ru' in call.data:       
        await sent_vk_audio(call)

    elif 'https://is.gd/' in call.data:
        await sent_vk_audio(call)

    else:
        pass
```

При нажатии на кнопки с callback-data `https://qps.ru/C8iL7` или `https://is.gd/9BSe6P`, произойдёт ошибка:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-54' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=InvalidHTTPUrlContent('Failed to get http url content')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 286, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\bot\bot\telegrambot.py", line 49, in callback_handler
    await sent_vk_audio(call)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\bot\bot\telegrambot.py", line 61, in sent_vk_audio
    await bot.send_audio(
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 568, in send_audio
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_AUDIO, payload, files)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.InvalidHTTPUrlContent: Failed to get http url content
```

Если прикрепить боту в Телеграме на aiogram эту callback_dat'y к инлайновой кнопке - `https://dl1.i-tsmusic.com/vk.play.php?id=371745454_456344136&vk_hash=375_133a3fe7458fafd604_8b62ea008b7113b395&hash=d4d83ea7e4650940a634238be6ab7ed5&name=badi-gr_bad-word.mp3`, произойдёт ошибка:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-30' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=ButtonDataInvalid('Button_data_invalid')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 286, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\bot\bot\telegrambot.py", line 52, in callback_handler
    await vk_search_status(call)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\bot\bot\telegrambot.py", line 88, in vk_search_status
    await vk_tracks_parser(call, html_code)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\bot\bot\telegrambot.py", line 118, in vk_tracks_parser
    await sent_vk_tracks_list(call, keyboard)
  File "c:\Users\Maxim\Desktop\bot\bot\telegrambot.py", line 127, in sent_vk_tracks_list
    await bot.send_video(
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 739, in send_video
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_VIDEO, payload, files)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 208, in request
    return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "C:\Users\Maxim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ButtonDataInvalid: Button_data_invalid
```

Я более 6-ти часов мучаюсь с этим, потому что единственный вариант, который мне наверное остается сделать это передавать на прямую ссылку для отправки ботом аудио, но это вовсе не то, что я бы хотел. Как можно решить эти проблемы, или хотя бы одну из их, чтобы бот спокойно мог отправлять музыку по ссылке людям?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, у Вас ошибка в реализации Ваших функций по отправке сообщения с аудиофайлом и по обработчику Callback-команды.

Во-первых, Вы повесили на Callback-обработчик `@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)`, что значит, что эта функция будет вызываться всегда, когда нажата любая callback-кнопка. Чтобы этого избежать, разумней будет создать отдельный триггер на отправку аудио по ссылке, например `SendAudio`.

Во-вторых, для отправки аудио Вы создали отдельную функцию, которая ничего не делает, кроме как вызов встроенного метода aiogram для отправки файла. Разделять код,  конечно, хорошо и правильно, но только там, где это действительно нужно. Я немного оптимизировал и протестировал Ваш код, всё работает. Можете посмотреть и сравнить с Вашим - его существенно меньше.

Если будут вопросы - спрашивайте.

```py
# Это раскомментируйте и добавьте в Вашу Inline-клавиатуру:
# InlineKeyboardButton(text="Скачать аудио", callback_data=f"SendAudio:https://qps.ru/C8iL7")

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.startswith('SendAudio:'))
async def download_audio_handler(call: CallbackQuery):
    url = call.data.split("SendAudio:")[1]

    if (
            'https://dl1.i-tsmusic.com' in url
            or 'https://qps.ru' in url
            or 'https://is.gd/' in url
    ):
        await bot.send_audio(
            call.message.chat.id,
            audio=url,
            caption='`  это тест`',
            parse_mode='MarkdownV2'
        )
```

Результат по нажатию кнопки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как ловить callback_data с остальных кнопок? Мне чтобы хотя бы как-то использовать ваш отправленный вариант необходимо 200 строк кода переписать

Comment: 200 это немного.

Смотрите, всю логику для отправки данных нужному обработчику Вы делаете здесь:
`@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: call.data.startswith('SendAudio:'))`

Это значит, что в этот обработчик попадут только те нажатые кнопки, которые начинаются с `SendAudio`.

Comment: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/dispatcher/filters.html#builtin-filters

Comment: Вроде работает в маленьком кусочке кода.. в моём телеграм боте вряд-ли работать будет...